# Should we synonymize [robocop] and [robocop-1987]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The [robocop](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robocop) tag has 11 questions and this tag wiki excerpt:

> A 1987 science fiction film starring Peter Weller and its titular character which have inspired a number of sequels, a "reboot", comic books, and video games. Set in the near future, a cybernetic law enforcer created from a murdered Detroit policeman wages war against criminals and corruption

The [robocop-1987](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robocop-1987) tag has 13 questions and this tag wiki excerpt:

> Robocop is a 1987 sci-fi film starring Peter Weller as cop Alex Murphy who is gunned down and then brought back to life as Robocop.

That seems familiar...

Both tags have full tag wikis. For what it's worth, every [robocop](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robocop)  question is also tagged [robocop-1987](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robocop-1987).

I suggest merging [robocop](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robocop) into [robocop-1987](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robocop-1987). Alternatively, we could make [robocop](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robocop) about the franchise by adding [robocop](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robocop) to [these four questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robocop-2014+or+robocop-1987+-robocop) and rewriting its tag wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added [robocop](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robocop) to the few [robocop-1987](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robocop-1987) or [robocop-2014](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robocop-2014) questions that didn't have it.

And @amarillo has now rewritten the [robocop](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robocop) tag wiki so that this tag applies to [the whole franchise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboCop_%28franchise%29) and not just the 1987 film.

Problem solved.

Comment: So we should put star-trek on all star-trek-reboot questions?

Comment: @CreationEdge [Technically yes](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9184/should-we-add-the-star-trek-tag-to-all-of-the-star-trek-questions-that-dont-h), though that's a big job that [won't be undertaken in the near future](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9207/when-should-we-do-another-tag-cleanup/9211#9211).

Comment: -2009 and reboot weren't in that question. But if that's the intent, to have a unifying tag between relaunches/reboots then we have compounded the naming convention problem.

Comment: @CreationEdge I'm not sure if having a unifying tag to cover reboots is a general principle though. Don't really know enough about it TBH. But since we do *have* a [tag:star-trek] tag, it seems reasonable to try to use it for all ST questions. (Ditto with [tag:doctor-who], although we don't have subtags for Classic Who and New Who.)

Comment: @CreationEdge people haven’t been consistent on the [tag:star-trek] tag for new questions. It’s a free-for-all... tag Star Trek questions however you want.

Comment: @amarillo I meant it as an example, more than ST specifically. There's a section on my tagging question about how our franchise names, esp. with reboots, is all screwed up. This worsens it, really. \*shrug\*

Comment: @CreationEdge The tagging situation will only get worse. Let’s just merge everything into [tag:question]. At least things will be consistent then.